# Parametric Equations for Circles

Tags: circles, parametric

Question - A circle has the equation:

$$(x-3)^2 + (y+1)^2 = 16$$

Find parametric equations to describe the circle given that:

(a) $x = 3 + 4\cos t$

(b) $x = 3 - 4\sin t$

Much appreciated if explanation can also be given! How can coefficient be negative when it relates to radius? Also why the $x$ part is $\sin$ when it’s usually always $\cos$?

Comment: You're given a parameterization for $x$; use it to find the corresponding parameterization for $y$. Also, $3-4\sin t=3+4\sin(-t)$; if $r(t)$ is the parameterization of some closed curve $C$, then $r(-t)$ is the same curve, but having opposite direction. Also, the choice of $x$ depending on $\sin$ or $\cos$ boils down to a $90^\circ$ rotation in the plot of $r(t)$, since $\cos(t-\frac\pi2)=\sin t$.

Answer (score 1):

(a) for given x, $y=-1+4\sin t.$ 
(b) for given x, $y=-1+4\cos t.$ 
Polar co-ordinate parametrization  must be $x=rcos t, y=rsin t. $  (b) is another such parametrization which satisfies the equation of the given circle.

Comment: Thanks. But y = rsint is the parametrization yet part (b) expresses y in terms of cos(t). That’s what confuses me?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Just plug your expression for $x$ into the original equation for the circle and solve for $y$.

For your second question, it doesn't matter which you choose for $\cos$, as long as together they satisfy the original equation. Using a different parameterization just means the point may not move around the circle in the "usual" way. The "usual" parameterization has the point start at the right side of the circle and move once around the circle counterclockwise. The direction, speed, and starting point can be varied by changing the parameterization.